# Mapping keys using Vim

Tags: vim

I want to switch to using vim but I have one major requirement for any editor:

I need to map the <kbd>`</kbd> key to the <kbd>=</kbd> key (as I've made the equals key the backspace key as the real backspace doesn't work (long story haha))

I can't seem to find anyway of doing this in vim (baring in mind I'm quite a noob at it.) There are a lot of references to `:map` but I can't get that to work how I want. Any help for a newbie?

Comment: Without `\`` you'll never be able to type inline code samples on Stack Overflow!

Comment: I would rather advise to remap Caps lock globally to space inside your window manager. **That** key is really useless.

Comment: @michael - That's why I'm only remapping it in vim :) I hardly use equals anywhere apart from when I'm coding and if I do need it, I can just press cmd+cntrl = to override it.

Comment: @Benoit - That's a good idea actually. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably accept the answer you commented on as fixing it... :)

Answer (score 7):

You just put this into your vimrc:

```
nnoremap ` =
xnoremap ` =
inoremap ` = 
cnoremap ` =
onoremap ` =
```

which will remap ` to = in normal, visual, insert, command-line and operator-pending modes resp.

See `:help map` for more information.

Note that it would probably better to remap `'` than `` ` ``, the latter being more useful (go to mark, keeping column number).

Comment: Thank you! The only problem with that is that it inserts a space after the ='s. I would map it to ' but I've got into a habit (one of the reasons I mapped backspace to equals because I just kept using one finger to backspace and it's such a hard habit to break.)

Comment: Scrap that problem, all fixed

Comment: This can probably be shortened by just using `map`, `lmap` and either `vmap` or `xmap` depending on if you want select mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this key-mapping:

```
:inoremap ` =
```

I also find it useful to use <kbd>Ctrl-H</kbd> as backspace key in `insert` mode.

Comment: if `=` had been remapped to space inside vim, this would have recursed. Always use `nore` version of map commands unless you need recursive maps. But here, probably the remapping of `=` to space has been done externally.